# CDI managed bean randomly found

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, cdi, weld, payara

I have an ear project split in 3 modules :

- a web module,
- a jar module containing my entities,
- an ejb module.

I have a class that looks like this :

```
public class UserServiceProviderEnterpriseImpl implements UserServiceProvider {
  @Override
  public UserService getUserService() {
    final BeanManager beanManager = CDI.current().getBeanManager();
    Bean<?> bean = beanManager.getBeans("userService").iterator().next();
    final CreationalContext<?> creationalContext = beanManager.createCreationalContext(bean);
    return (UserService) beanManager.getReference(bean, bean.getBeanClass(), creationalContext);
  }
}
```

This class belongs to the entity module.

An instance of that class is created in a @PreUpdate hook in a @MappedSuperclass of my @Entity object. This class (and the said hook), look like this :

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public abstract class BusinessObject<T extends Serializable> implements Cloneable {

  // [...]

  @PrePersist
  @PreUpdate
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  private void _prePersist() {

    // [...]

    final User currentUser = getUserServiceProvider().getUserService().getCurrentUser();

    // [...]
  }

  private static UserServiceProvider getUserServiceProvider() {
    try {
      return SenyuProperties.Core.getUserServiceProviderClass().newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Erreur lors de l'instanciation du UserServiceProvider", e);
    }
  }

  // [...]
}
```

The entity class extending this one is in the same module as the UserServiceProviderEnterpriseImpl class.

My problem here appears at this line :

```
Bean<?> bean = beanManager.getBeans("userService").iterator().next();
```

...which sometimes throws a NoSuchElementException (cause of empty Set returned by the BeanManager#getBeans method), but sometimes does not. This issue seems to be deployment-wide, since I can deploy my ear and this will happen on every call to the getUserService() method, but after a redeploy the same scenario can work totally fine (the BeanManager#getBeans method doesn't return an empty Set anymore).

So my question is : why is this code behaving the way it does? Am I doing something wrong? What can be the source of this randomness?

If this can help, my managed bean looks like this (it belongs to the web module) :

```
@Named("userService")
@SessionScoped
public class UserServiceEnterpriseImpl implements UserService, Serializable {
  @EJB
  private UserDAO dao;
  private User user;

  @Override
  public User getCurrentUser() {
    return user;
  }

  @PostConstruct
  private void initCurrentUser() {
    user = dao.findByUsername((String)SecurityUtils.getSubject().getPrincipal());
  }
}
```

I'm working with Payara 4.1.1.162.

**UPDATE**

Things I already tried but didn't work:

- using the initialize-in-order tag in application.xml (set to true) and changing the order of the modules,
- updating Payara to the latest build available (4.1.1.163),
- manually deploying the app through command line (I usually do that from IntelliJ),
- removing the "static" keyword in the BusinessObject#getUserServiceProvider() method,
- all that after I changed the getUserService() method code to use the solution provided by this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40328987/7090063.

As requested, here is my one and only beans.xml, that reside in my web module in the src/main/webapp/WEB-INF directory:

```
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       version="1.1" bean-discovery-mode="all">
  <interceptors>
    <class>org.senyu.intranet.managedbean.ShiroSecuredInterceptor</class>
  </interceptors>
</beans>
```

And this is a summary of the structure of my ear with the classes I mentioned until now:

```
ear
+-ejb (jar)
+-entity (jar)
| +-src
|   +-main
|     +-java
|       +-org
|         +-senyu
|           +-intranet
|             +-entity
|               +-user
|               | +-UserServiceProviderEnterpriseImpl
|               +-contrat
|                 +-Contrat // the class extending BusinessObject.
|                           // The latter reside in a dependency
|                           // (core-common-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar).
|                           // The full list is right beneath.
|                           // The UserService and UserServiceProvider
|                           // interfaces also come from this jar.
+-web
  +-src
    +-main
    | +-java
    |   +-org
    |     +-senyu
    |       +-intranet
    |         +-managedbean
    |           +-UserServiceEnterpriseImpl
    |           +-ShiroSecuredInterceptor // @Interceptor class with an @AroundInvoke annotated method
    +-webapp
      +-WEB-INF
        +-beans.xml
```

And those are the jar packed up in the WEB-INF/lib directory of my war file :

```
antlr-2.7.7.jar
aopalliance-repackaged-2.5.0-b05.jar
bootstrap-3.3.7-1.jar
cdi-api-1.1.jar
classmate-1.3.0.jar
commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar
commons-codec-1.10.jar
commons-lang3-3.4.jar
commons-logging-1.2.jar
core-common-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar // I developed this...
core-enterprise-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar // ...and that too.
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
el-api-2.2.jar
geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar
gson-2.7.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-core-5.2.3.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
hk2-api-2.5.0-b05.jar
hk2-locator-2.5.0-b05.jar
hk2-utils-2.5.0-b05.jar
jackson-annotations-2.8.0.jar
jackson-core-2.8.3.jar
jackson-databind-2.8.3.jar
jandex-2.0.0.Final.jar
javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar
javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
javax.inject-1.jar
javax.inject-2.5.0-b05.jar
javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar
jboss-interceptors-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Beta1.jar
jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar
jersey-client-2.23.2.jar
jersey-common-2.23.2.jar
jersey-guava-2.23.2.jar
jersey-media-jaxb-2.23.2.jar
jersey-mvc-2.23.2.jar
jersey-server-2.23.2.jar
jquery-1.12.4.jar
jsr250-api-1.0.jar
log4j-api-2.6.2.jar
log4j-core-2.6.2.jar
osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar
primefaces-6.0.jar
servlet-api-2.4.jar
shiro-core-1.3.0.jar
shiro-web-1.3.0.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar
validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
```

**UPDATE 2**

I created a logger for org.weld.jboss in Payara. Here is what I get when it works :

```
Sending PAT using the default event resolver: [BackedAnnotatedType] public @Named @SessionScoped class org.senyu.intranet.managedbean.UserServiceEnterpriseImpl]]
WELD-001536: Found [] constructors annotated with @Inject for [EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl] public @SessionScoped @Named class org.senyu.intranet.managedbean.UserServiceEnterpriseImpl]]
WELD-000002: Exactly one constructor ([EnhancedAnnotatedConstructorImpl] public org.senyu.intranet.managedbean.UserServiceEnterpriseImpl()) defined, using it as the bean constructor for [EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl] public @SessionScoped @Named class org.senyu.intranet.managedbean.UserServiceEnterpriseImpl]]
WELD-000004: Exactly one post construct method ([EnhancedAnnotatedMethodImpl] @PostConstruct private org.senyu.intranet.managedbean.UserServiceEnterpriseImpl.initCurrentUser()) for [EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl] public @SessionScoped @Named class org.senyu.intranet.managedbean.UserServiceEnterpriseImpl]]
WELD-001536: Found [] constructors annotated with @Inject for [EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl] public @SessionScoped @Named class org.senyu.intranet.managedbean.UserServiceEnterpriseImpl]]
WELD-000002: Exactly one constructor ([EnhancedAnnotatedConstructorImpl] public org.senyu.intranet.managedbean.UserServiceEnterpriseImpl()) defined, using it as the bean constructor for [EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl] public @SessionScoped @Named class org.senyu.intranet.managedbean.UserServiceEnterpriseImpl]]
WELD-000012: Building bean metadata for class org.senyu.intranet.managedbean.UserServiceEnterpriseImpl]]
WELD-000010: Using qualifiers [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default(), @javax.inject.Named(value=userService), @javax.enterprise.inject.Any()] for Managed Bean [class org.senyu.intranet.managedbean.UserServiceEnterpriseImpl] with qualifiers [@Default @Named @Any]]]
WELD-000014: Using name userService for Managed Bean [class org.senyu.intranet.managedbean.UserServiceEnterpriseImpl] with qualifiers [@Default @Named @Any]]]
WELD-000016: Using scope interface javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped for Managed Bean [class org.senyu.intranet.managedbean.UserServiceEnterpriseImpl] with qualifiers [@Default @Named @Any]]]
WELD-000106: Bean: Managed Bean [class org.senyu.intranet.managedbean.UserServiceEnterpriseImpl] with qualifiers [@Default @Named @Any]]]
WELD-001538: Created context instance for bean Managed Bean [class org.senyu.intranet.managedbean.UserServiceEnterpriseImpl] with qualifiers [@Default @Named @Any] identified as WELD%ManagedBean%intranet-ear|intranet-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war|org.senyu.intranet.managedbean.UserServiceEnterpriseImpl|null|false]]
WELD-001542: Retrieving/generating proxy class org.senyu.intranet.managedbean.UserServiceEnterpriseImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy]]
WELD-001541: Adding method to proxy: public org.senyu.core.common.user.User org.senyu.intranet.managedbean.UserServiceEnterpriseImpl.getCurrentUser()]]
WELD-001541: Adding method to proxy: private void org.senyu.intranet.managedbean.UserServiceEnterpriseImpl.initCurrentUser()]]
WELD-001543: Created Proxy class of type class org.senyu.intranet.managedbean.UserServiceEnterpriseImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy supporting interfaces [interface org.senyu.core.common.user.UserService, interface java.io.Serializable, interface org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.LifecycleMixin, interface org.jboss.weld.interceptor.util.proxy.TargetInstanceProxy, interface org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyObject]]]
WELD-001506: Created new client proxy of type class org.senyu.intranet.managedbean.UserServiceEnterpriseImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy for bean Managed Bean [class org.senyu.intranet.managedbean.UserServiceEnterpriseImpl] with qualifiers [@Default @Named @Any] with ID WELD%ManagedBean%intranet-ear|intranet-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war|org.senyu.intranet.managedbean.UserServiceEnterpriseImpl|null|false]]
WELD-001507: Located client proxy of type class org.senyu.intranet.managedbean.UserServiceEnterpriseImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy for bean Managed Bean [class org.senyu.intranet.managedbean.UserServiceEnterpriseImpl] with qualifiers [@Default @Named @Any]]]
WELD-000200: Looked for WELD%ManagedBean%intranet-ear|intranet-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war|org.senyu.intranet.managedbean.UserServiceEnterpriseImpl|null|false and got null in org.jboss.weld.context.beanstore.http.LazySessionBeanStore@3feb0ef2]]
WELD-000200: Looked for WELD%ManagedBean%intranet-ear|intranet-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war|org.senyu.intranet.managedbean.UserServiceEnterpriseImpl|null|false and got null in org.jboss.weld.context.beanstore.http.LazySessionBeanStore@3feb0ef2]]
WELD-000200: Looked for WELD%ManagedBean%intranet-ear|intranet-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war|org.senyu.intranet.managedbean.UserServiceEnterpriseImpl|null|false and got null in org.jboss.weld.context.beanstore.http.LazySessionBeanStore@3feb0ef2]]
WELD-000200: Looked for WELD%ManagedBean%intranet-ear|intranet-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war|org.senyu.intranet.managedbean.UserServiceEnterpriseImpl|null|false and got null in org.jboss.weld.context.beanstore.http.LazySessionBeanStore@3feb0ef2]]
WELD-000220: Added WELD_S#WELD%ManagedBean%intranet-ear|intranet-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war|org.senyu.intranet.managedbean.UserServiceEnterpriseImpl|null|false to session 0fcfe5dc9c8fb5d583f9b90ce7ae]]
WELD-000202: Added ForwardingBean userService for Managed Bean [class org.senyu.intranet.managedbean.UserServiceEnterpriseImpl] with qualifiers [@Default @Named @Any] with key WELD%ManagedBean%intranet-ear|intranet-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war|org.senyu.intranet.managedbean.UserServiceEnterpriseImpl|null|false to org.jboss.weld.context.beanstore.http.LazySessionBeanStore@3feb0ef2]]
```

And when it doesn't :

```
Sending PAT using the default event resolver: [BackedAnnotatedType] public @Named @SessionScoped class org.senyu.intranet.managedbean.UserServiceEnterpriseImpl]]
WELD-001536: Found [] constructors annotated with @Inject for [EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl] public @SessionScoped @Named class org.senyu.intranet.managedbean.UserServiceEnterpriseImpl]]
WELD-000002: Exactly one constructor ([EnhancedAnnotatedConstructorImpl] public org.senyu.intranet.managedbean.UserServiceEnterpriseImpl()) defined, using it as the bean constructor for [EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl] public @SessionScoped @Named class org.senyu.intranet.managedbean.UserServiceEnterpriseImpl]]
WELD-000004: Exactly one post construct method ([EnhancedAnnotatedMethodImpl] @PostConstruct private org.senyu.intranet.managedbean.UserServiceEnterpriseImpl.initCurrentUser()) for [EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl] public @SessionScoped @Named class org.senyu.intranet.managedbean.UserServiceEnterpriseImpl]]
WELD-001536: Found [] constructors annotated with @Inject for [EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl] public @SessionScoped @Named class org.senyu.intranet.managedbean.UserServiceEnterpriseImpl]]
WELD-000002: Exactly one constructor ([EnhancedAnnotatedConstructorImpl] public org.senyu.intranet.managedbean.UserServiceEnterpriseImpl()) defined, using it as the bean constructor for [EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl] public @SessionScoped @Named class org.senyu.intranet.managedbean.UserServiceEnterpriseImpl]]
WELD-000012: Building bean metadata for class org.senyu.intranet.managedbean.UserServiceEnterpriseImpl]]
WELD-000010: Using qualifiers [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default(), @javax.inject.Named(value=userService), @javax.enterprise.inject.Any()] for Managed Bean [class org.senyu.intranet.managedbean.UserServiceEnterpriseImpl] with qualifiers [@Default @Named @Any]]]
WELD-000014: Using name userService for Managed Bean [class org.senyu.intranet.managedbean.UserServiceEnterpriseImpl] with qualifiers [@Default @Named @Any]]]
WELD-000016: Using scope interface javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped for Managed Bean [class org.senyu.intranet.managedbean.UserServiceEnterpriseImpl] with qualifiers [@Default @Named @Any]]]
WELD-000106: Bean: Managed Bean [class org.senyu.intranet.managedbean.UserServiceEnterpriseImpl] with qualifiers [@Default @Named @Any]]]
  HHH000346: Error during managed flush [WELD-001308: Unable to resolve any beans for Type: interface org.senyu.core.common.user.UserService; Qualifiers: [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default(), @javax.enterprise.inject.Any()]]]]
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: WELD-001308: Unable to resolve any beans for Type: interface org.senyu.core.common.user.UserService; Qualifiers: [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default(), @javax.enterprise.inject.Any()]
    at org.senyu.intranet.entity.user.UserServiceProviderEnterpriseImpl.getUserService(UserServiceProviderEnterpriseImpl.java:17)
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: WELD-001308: Unable to resolve any beans for Type: interface org.senyu.core.common.user.UserService; Qualifiers: [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default(), @javax.enterprise.inject.Any()]
    at org.senyu.intranet.entity.user.UserServiceProviderEnterpriseImpl.getUserService(UserServiceProviderEnterpriseImpl.java:17)
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: WELD-001308: Unable to resolve any beans for Type: interface org.senyu.core.common.user.UserService; Qualifiers: [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default(), @javax.enterprise.inject.Any()]
    at org.senyu.intranet.entity.user.UserServiceProviderEnterpriseImpl.getUserService(UserServiceProviderEnterpriseImpl.java:17)
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: WELD-001308: Unable to resolve any beans for Type: interface org.senyu.core.common.user.UserService; Qualifiers: [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default(), @javax.enterprise.inject.Any()]
    at org.senyu.intranet.entity.user.UserServiceProviderEnterpriseImpl.getUserService(UserServiceProviderEnterpriseImpl.java:17)
```

Comment: Did you find a way to resolve this? I am bumping into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using an iterator to look up a bean is not correct.  The set may be empty, implying no beans of that type exist yet.

Since you're already using CDI 1.1 API, better off using `CDI.current().select(UserService.class).get()`

Comment: I tried your solution, but ended up observing the same random behavior I described. More specifically, I get this exception (when it doesn't work) : `org.jboss.weld.exceptions.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: WELD-001308: Unable to resolve any beans for Type: interface org.senyu.core.common.user.UserService; Qualifiers: []`.

Comment: Can you share the `beans.xml` of all three of your modules @GabrielBarthélémy?

Comment: In addition, can you specify where each of the listed classes are located within your EAR, and if your WAR file includes any extra JARs within it.

Comment: I updated my question. If you need anything else, just ask. :-)

Comment: You get an `UnsatisfiedResolutionExc` when using `CDI.current().select(UserService.class).get()` because `UserService` has `@Named` qualifier and it does not match the select. Try adding `@Default` qualifier under `@Named` qualifier. Or improve the select command: `CDI.current().select(UserService.class, new AnnotationLiteral<Any>(){}).get()`

Comment: Yes, but also he doesn't have a `beans.xml` in the entity JAR, its not required that the context propagates there.  So that may explain the "random" part of this.

Comment: I tried both of your solutions and none of them is working. @John the Java EE 7 specs seems to say that beans.xml is no longer required (https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/cdi-adv001.htm). Moreover, my UserProvider session scoped bean residing in another module, the limitation induced by bean-discovery-mode="annotated" (the behavior for providing no beans.xml, the module becoming then an implicit bean archive) doesn't seem to apply here anyway.

Comment: I updated my post with a sample of the logs I'm getting from weld concerning my session scoped bean when it is found and when it is not.

Comment: Gah.  I just reread your question.  Session scope is only applicable to the WAR file.  The EAR and its non-war libraries need not propagate the session scope from your WAR.  I would really recommend you to not use an EAR and just use a WAR.  Much cleaner for CDI.

Comment: Maybe I'll move to a simple WAR later yeah, it really seems much simpler, but in the meantime, is there any way I can explicitly propagate the session scope to the other modules of my EAR? And still, that doesn't explain why CDI sometimes find my bean and sometimes it does not (I don't change anything between each Payara's restart and EAR's redeployment). Imho this behavior is somehow indicating that it should normally works, don't you think? Oh, and could you quote the specs or a source too regarding this session propagation thing between EAR modules please?